# How do I attach a debugger to a process using Invoke-WmiMethod?

Tags: powershell, debugging, wmic

I have a process already running on a remote computer and I'd like to attach a debugger to it. I would like to use Invoke-WMIMethod so that when I disconnect from that remote session, the debugger will remain attached to the process in the background.

So far I have:

```
$Qry = "Select * from Win32_Process where ProcessID like $ID"
$CimIO = Get-WMIObject -Query $Qry
Invoke-WMIMethod -InputObject $CimIO -Class Win32_Process -Name AttachDebugger -AsJob
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WmiMethod -InputObject $CimIO -Class Win32_process -Name Attac ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WmiMethod], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWmiMethod
```

Am I on the right track? When I try other Methods from Win32_Process (like GetOwner), I get the same error message. What's going on here?

EDIT:

Perhaps I am going about this all wrong: My understanding was that the query would return a pointer to the running process which could then be used as an input object to Invoke-WmiMethod.

Debug-Process requires that a separate debugger already be downloaded and installed on the machine whereas "AttachDebugger" as a method is installed by default (at least I'm assuming since it was on a fresh copy of Windows 10). The reason why I want to use built-in methods only is because I would like this script to be usable in a production environment where I will not have control over what's installed on the computers.

I found the method by running the script found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/10670e14-4cf1-4ce5-99d0-fc4ca80dac2c) which found the method residing in Win32_Process. I went with Invoke-WmiMethod because when -AsJob is invoked, it [creates a job locally on the remote computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod?view=powershell-5.1) where the process I'm sending to a debugger resides.

Thank you for the help and I'm sorry for the confusion: this is part of my first powershell script.

The use case is follows:
In a SIEM environment the user sees a program on the network acting suspicious. The user then remotely logs into the victim computer and freezes the suspicious thread by sending it to a debugger. The user then logs out and will get back to analyzing the thread later. The thread will remain frozen until that time.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never tried or had a reason to try this use case.

However, AsJob is used for long running tasks. You are only querying to get a listing of a single Process ID and once that listing is provided, the job is done / stopped / completed.

There is nothing to attach to. Lastly, where are you getting this method --- AttachDebugger  -- from?

There is no such method using the Get-WmiObject or Invoke-WmiMethod cmdlet parameters. That is what the error is about

Why are you not just using the built-in cmdlet for this effort.

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Debug-Process).Parameters
Get-help -Name Debug-Process -Examples
Get-help -Name Debug-Process -Full
Get-help -Name Debug-Process -Online
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I edited my post above to answer your questions.